# Stop Continuation Task upon exception thrown from parent task

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library

I want to make sure that the continuation task will not happen if an expection is thrown in the parallel loop

```
 var parent = tf.StartNew(() =>

    Parallel.ForEach(QuestionsLangConstants.questionLangs.Values, (i, state) =>
          {
             try
               {
                 qrepo.UploadQuestions(QWorkBook.Worksheets[i.QSheet],
                 QWorkBook.Worksheets[i.QTranslationSheet], i, prog);
               }
             catch (Exception ex)
               {

                 context.Dispose();
                 state.Break();
                //make sure the execution fails  
               }
          }));

var finalTast = parent.ContinueWith(i =>
            {
                if (context != null)
                {
                    DialogResult result = 
     MessageBox.Show("Do You Want to Commit the Questions?", "Save to DB",
      MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Question);

                    if (result.Equals(DialogResult.OK))
                    {
                       //Do Stuff here
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: Maybe with an `if (!i.IsFaulted) ...`, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.isfaulted.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Don't swallow exception, and run continue only for not on faulted

```
var parent = tf.StartNew(() =>

                        Parallel.ForEach(QuestionsLangConstants.questionLangs.Values, (i, state) =>
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                qrepo.UploadQuestions(QWorkBook.Worksheets[i.QSheet], QWorkBook.Worksheets[i.QTranslationSheet], i, prog);

                            }
                           catch (Exception ex)
                           {

                              context.Dispose();
                                state.Break();
                             //make sure the execution fails
                             throw;
                            }
                        }));

var finalTast = parent.ContinueWith(i =>
            {
                if (context != null)
                {
                    DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Do You Want to Commit the Questions?", "Save to DB", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Question);

                    if (result.Equals(DialogResult.OK))
                    {
                       //Do Stuff here
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                }
        }, TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnFaulted);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the [ContinueWith overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321576.aspx) that takes in `TaskContinuationOptions` and allow the execption to bubble up

```
 var parent = tf.StartNew(() =>

    Parallel.ForEach(QuestionsLangConstants.questionLangs.Values, (i, state) =>
          {
             try
               {
                 qrepo.UploadQuestions(QWorkBook.Worksheets[i.QSheet],
                 QWorkBook.Worksheets[i.QTranslationSheet], i, prog);
               }
             catch (Exception ex)
               {

                 context.Dispose();
                 state.Break();
                //make sure the execution fails  
                throw; //<-- This line was added to stop the continuation task.
               }
          }));

var finalTast = parent.ContinueWith(i =>
            {
               //...
            }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);
```

Comment: Then should I create a parent.continueWith that `TaskContinuationOptions.OnFaulted` that will throw an exception message? The one that cause the initial cathc to begin with?

Comment: just throwing it inside the continuation task won't do anything for you, however you could put your logging inside there, or display a message box showing that a error happened.

Comment: yes that's what I meant. Thanks. I will try and let you know.